# Can the values greater than x be group in a dropdown?

Tags: php

I am customizing a theme in wp and I have a dropdown with values from 1-10. The values are from a custom field (text field)

I want to have it like (1,2,3,4,5+). When I choose 5+ to show all results with field value >= 5

This is the code

```
 while($i < 10 ){
       $i++;
       $rooms_select_list.='<li data-value="'.esc_attr($i).'"  value="'.esc_attr($i).'">'.$i.'</li>';
                }
```

This is what I tried

```
while($i < 6 ){
     $i++;
     $rooms_select_list.='<li data-value="'.esc_attr($i).'"  value="'.esc_attr($i).'">'.$i.'</li>';
     if($i== 5){
     $rooms_select_list.='<li data-value="'.esc_attr($i).'"  value="'.esc_attr($i).'">'.$i+.'</li>';
                        }
                    }
```

But something is not right I think because my dropdown looks the same.

All code section

```html
else if ( $show_dropdowns=='yes' && ( $adv_search_what[$key]=='property rooms' ||  $adv_search_what[$key]=='property bedrooms' ||  $adv_search_what[$key]=='property bathrooms') ){
                    $i=0;
                    if (function_exists('icl_translate') ){
                        $label     =   icl_translate('wpestate','wp_estate_custom_search_'.$adv_search_label[$key], $adv_search_label[$key] ) ;
                    }else{
                       $label= $adv_search_label[$key];
                    }
                    $rooms_select_list =   ' <li role="presentation" data-value="all">'.  $label.'</li>';
                    /////////////////////////////////
                   
                        
                    while($i < 10 ){
                        $i++;
                        $rooms_select_list.='<li data-value="'.esc_attr($i).'"  value="'.esc_attr($i).'">'.$i.'</li>';
                    }

                    $return_string=wpestate_build_dropdown_adv($appendix,'search-'.$slug,$slug,$label,'all',$slug,$rooms_select_list);

                }else{
                    $custom_fields = wpresidence_get_option( 'wp_estate_custom_fields', '');

                    $i=0;
                    $found_dropdown=0;
                    ///////////////////////////////// dropdown check
                    if( !empty($custom_fields)){
                        
                    while($i< count($custom_fields) ){
                            $name       =   $custom_fields[$i][0];

                            $slug_drop       =   str_replace(' ','-',$name);

                            if( $slug_drop == $adv_search_what[$key] && $custom_fields[$i][2]=='dropdown' ){

                                $found_dropdown=1;
                                $front_name=sanitize_title($adv_search_label[$key]);
                                if (function_exists('icl_translate') ){
                                    $initial_key = apply_filters('wpml_translate_single_string', trim($adv_search_label[$key]),'custom field value','custom_field_value'.$adv_search_label[$key] );
                                    $action_select_list =   ' <li role="presentation" data-value="all"> '. $initial_key .'</li>';
                                }else{
                                    $action_select_list =   ' <li role="presentation" data-value="all">'.  $adv_search_label[$key].'</li>';
                                }

                                $dropdown_values_array=explode(',',$custom_fields[$i][4]);

                                foreach($dropdown_values_array as $drop_key=>$value_drop){
                                    $original_value_drop    =$value_drop;
                                    if (function_exists('icl_translate') ){

                                        $value_drop = apply_filters('wpml_translate_single_string', trim($value_drop),'custom field value','custom_field_value'.$value_drop );
                                    }
                                    $action_select_list .=   ' <li role="presentation" data-value="'.trim(esc_attr($original_value_drop) ).'">'.trim($value_drop).'</li>';
                                }
                                $front_name=sanitize_title($adv_search_label[$key]);
                                if(isset($_GET[$front_name]) && $_GET[$front_name]!='' && $_GET[$front_name]!='all'){
                                    $advanced_drop_value= esc_attr( wp_kses( $_GET[$front_name], $allowed_html) );
                                    $advanced_drop_value1='';
                                }else{
                                    $advanced_drop_value= $label;
                                    $advanced_drop_value1='all';
                                }
                                $front_name=  wpestate_limit45($front_name);
                                $return_string=wpestate_build_dropdown_adv($appendix,$front_name,$front_name,$advanced_drop_value,$advanced_drop_value1,$front_name,$action_select_list);


                            }
                            $i++;
                        }
                    }
                    ///////////////////// end dropdown check
```

Comment: Second code block, in the statement ($rooms_select_list. . . )   you've included a backtick instead of an apotstrophe. Also, the + character is outside of the string.

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? It could be easier to gather the options first, and build the markup later, to avoid mixing logic and HTML

Comment: Thanks. I edit it. But now I have 5 twice. So I write a condition wrong

Comment: @NicoHaase can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

// You're checking if the current value equals 5, but should be checking for equals to and exceeds 5

```
change

while($i < 6 ){
     $i++;
     $rooms_select_list.='<li data-value="'.esc_attr($i).'"  value="'.esc_attr($i).'">'.$i.'</li>';
     if($i== 5){
     $rooms_select_list.='<li data-value="'.esc_attr($i).'"  value="'.esc_attr($i).'">'.$i.+’</li>';
                        }
                    }

to



   for($i=1;$i<10;$i++){
        if($i<5) {
            $rooms_select_list.='<li data-value="'.esc_attr($i).'"  value="'.esc_attr($i).'">'.$i.'</li>';
        } else if($i==5){
            $rooms_select_list.='<li data-value="'.esc_attr($i).'"  value="'.esc_attr($i).'">5+</li>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your suggested for loop would still create ten options, having half of them say `5+`. But they only want _one_ option with that value.

Comment: And `else if($i>=5)` also makes rather little sense. If the value was _not_ `<5`, then _what else_ could it possibly be at this point now? A simple `else` is enough here.

Comment: you are correct, read the question wrong. Will update my answer

Comment: Thanks guys. @Erik code works by making values in dropdown like I want, but when selecting 5+ it shows only listings with value 5. I need to show all listings with value >=5

Comment: @seby _"I need to show all listings with value >=5"_ - then you probably need to modify the part where this option value is actually used to create a database query, as well. If that currently does something like `WHERE column = value-from-form-here`, that `=` won't change to a `>=` on its own.

Comment: And I can't tell you either, because the code you have shown so far, does not appear to be the part that actually fetches any data from the database, but only the creation of those dropdown fields. (Which is understandable, if it is supposed template code, because data selection does not belong into the template to begin with.)

Comment: You did not even make it clear in your question, _what kind_ of data you actually want to filter here. _"When I choose 5+ to show all results with field value >= 5"_ - "results" meaning what - WP posts, pages? A CPT? Something else?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Hard day. I'm using the [WPresidence theme](https://help.wpresidence.net/article/advanced-search-form-theme-options). They have post type as Properties/Listings. Each listing can have some custom fields. The field that I want to change is rooms.  Example in this search on Bedrooms